# To what extent is it true that both too much stress and too much relaxation lead to mental shortcuts?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias, rationality

Sometimes rational thought seems to be bypassed in the brain for more automatic behaviour (shortcuts, instinct, intuition, heuristics):

- In [The Willpower Instinct](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10865206-the-willpower-instinct?ac=1&from_search=true) by Kelly McGonigal she writes that high stress can cause automatic *'fight-or-flight'* behaviour, which causes the prefrontal cortex for rational thinking to be bypassed. Relaxing yourself can help in reversing the process and becoming more rational again. She calls it the 'stop-and-think' response.
- In [Thinking Fast and Slow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11468377-thinking-fast-and-slow?ac=1&from_search=true) by Daniel Kahneman he writes that when someone feels confident that there are no threats facing him their system 2 (rational system) becomes lazy, *'cognitive ease'* and starts to depend on heuristics too much.

So, apparently mental shortcuts happen both in situations of high stress *(fight or flight)* and in situations of confidence and relaxation *(cognitive ease)*.

Question: To what extent is it indeed **factually** true that both too much relaxation and too much stress can cause mental shortcuts? Please elaborate...

Comment: I changed the question to address the criticism that put this question on hold. Now how can I get this question to not on hold anymore?